# LED Flame Emulation

Tags: led

My wife bought these **flameless candles**.  They have 3 LEDs in them that have a seemingly random flicker to them. (Get bright, fade out a bit, fade in a bit etc...).  Since there are three when you see it through wax it looks like a flame flickering.  Very cool.

I though it would be a fun project to get back into electronics.  I am a computer engineer but I fell into software - so while I understand concepts and how things work, I have no clue how to start this unless I got a pic chip or whatever people use now.

Any suggestions?  The simpler(cheaper) the better.  I just need some general ideas to get me pointed in the right direction.  What kind of circuits should I be looking at or does this need to be done with some kind of controller like a PIC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a red/yellow or green/red bi-colour LED, you can also shift the 'flame' position.

Flame flickering isn't random in the sense of white noise. You'll get good results if you [drive it with a melody](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Listen-to-Light/step8/LED-tea-light-candles-play-music-for-some-reason/). The [AVR Butterfly](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=3146) comes with Fur Elise preprogrammed, I believe. A fun way to experiment with this may be to build a [classic crystal radio](http://www.techlib.com/electronics/crystal.html) and have it drive an LED (would have to be powered to drive LED); or with a *line out* audio jack. Two more options are to capture the driver signal going to your consumer LEDs with an oscilloscope, or measure a candle's flicker with a photocell (photodiode). Putting together the little bits of analog buffering required to measure a candle's flicker accurately may be just what you need to get back in the spirit!

[Here are analog 'flicker' circuits.](http://www.horrorseek.com/home/halloween/wolfstone/Flicker/flktch_FlickerTechniques.html) Many of them appear to be higher power. Parallax put together [this How-To: Tricks and Treats with LEDs](http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/cols/nv/vol6/col/nv126.pdf).

Comment: I got a decent flame going using an Arduino.  Still want to get a hardware solution going though.  I'll keep you guys posted.

Comment: @Blankasaurus, What is your 'flicker algorithm'?

Comment: Three LEDs with offset sinewaves.  The frequency of the waves gets changed randomly too.(This is also offset)

Answer (score 3):

If you want an all electronics solution I guess I would build three slow oscillators, one for each LED. For a more random effect oscillators could influence the other oscillators' frequencies.
This requires a fair amount of discrete components, though, and I wonder if the flameless candles don't use a microcontroller. (A 15 component discrete solution can easily be more expensive than a small microcontroller.)

Your choice for a solution will depend on whether you want to be an electronics engineer or a software engineer. If you plan to go ahead with microcontrollers I would suggest a uC solution. Today microcontrollers are easy to use, but still have a learning curve, depending on the tools available.

Answer (score 3):

I created something similar, it just goes through some colors on an RGB led. I Used a MSP430G2211 uC that came with the [launch pad](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP430_LaunchPad_%28MSP-EXP430G2%29?DCMP=launchpad&HQS=Other+OT+launchpadwiki). My project [link](http://justinstech.org/projects/msp430-rgb-flower-pot/). The code could be easily changed to create a flame or flicker effect and by changing the leds.

Answer (score 2):

There's an instructable on how to create a realistic flickering flame effect with LED's, using an Atmega uC (on an Arduino board): http://www.instructables.com/id/Realistic-Fire-Effect-with-Arduino-and-LEDs/

Easy hardware setup, easy code. Any controller capable of PWM on 3 outputs would work.

Comment: PWM can be done purely in software and since the program would be doing very little there isn't much hurt by having it in software. You can probably get a micro much cheaper when you remove the hardware PWM requirement.

Comment: If I wanted to create these in quantity could I do it cheaply or are Atmega uC's for more of a hobbyist type thing?

Comment: @Blankasaurus, The Arduino is mostly a hobbyist's tool, but [the ATmega line](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/param_table.asp?family_id=607&OrderBy=part_no&Direction=ASC) isn't limited to that demographic. They are used in industry, just like [Renesas](http://am.renesas.com/), Motorola, or [Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2551).

Comment: @Kellenjb: true, but he said 'as simple as possible' :-)

@Blankasaurus: what @tyblu said

Comment: @tyblu don't forget the TI micros. @Vincent Van Den Berghe He put cheap in () after the simple, so I figured by simple he meant cheap, not simple program. Either way, software PWM is rather simple. @Blankasaurus You can get micros for very cheap. The cost is usually pretty closely tied to how much memory it has and since you don't need much you can get a very cheap one. In large quantities you can get micros for less then $1.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite easy to do this with no microcontroller. You use automatically color changing LEDs - these have three LEDs (red, green and blue diodes) with built in circuitry which makes them change color through the rainbow. Unfortunately, I've only found rainbow LEDs - I haven't yet found bicolor (e.g. red/yellow) LEDs which change color automatically, though I imagine a simple filter to block out blue and green light and only allow yellow and red would work well - you could probably find these online or at a camera shop.)

Simply put the three or four LEDs in series with each other and drive them with about 9V (dc.) To limit the current through the array put a 220 to 470 ohm resistor in series with them. (I didn't do this on my first attempt and found the LEDs were very dim the next day because they had been damaged by the excess current.) The LEDs flicker randomly because the voltage drop across each varies which also causes them to restart occasionally. Also, they are not precise so the frequency on each is different which causes each LED to follow its own pattern. I'm currently using these as a christmas decoration on my tree; I use 5 in series with a 560 ohm 1/4w resistor and run them at about 18V.

Comment: Interesting... I actually wanted to do this with red LEDs only.  I also want something a little more predictable/controllable - thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question specifies that LEDs are the required illuminating device, but if you want to scale things up a bit, you can make a very convincing flame effect with a yellow 25w GLS incandescent bulb and a standard fluorescent tube starter.

All you need to do, is connect the starter in series with the bulb, and it will happily flicker on and off indefinitely.

Connect a few bulbs, all with their own starters, and mix up the colours between yellow orange and red to make a nice warm fireglow effect.

Very simple, and few parts required!